# How to fix copy/paste layout bug in EditText

Tags: android

I have own EditText in layout, I use it to search. but select the text of into EditText bug in top of my layout.

please see below photo to understand my mean 
[image]

layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#000"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tellfa.smsbox.Search_page">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/search_page_hing"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/search_hint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_foreground_material_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Appbar code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolbarTheme"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
>
```

how to fix it or change top of layout background ?

Comment: Show some code or more explanation!

Comment: @Harry, edit topic and send layout code. please see it

Comment: Just change background in app_bar.xml. Or post that file in question.

Comment: @Harry, sent app_bar.xml code. background is use and set color! how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your layout like:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    ..
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Also make sure that your project uses style

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tell me if it works for you!

Comment: tnx, but work it. please see the picture after update layout with your code : http://s9.uploads.im/Nga7h.jpg

Comment: Then there may be issue in MyCustomToolbarTheme.

Comment: <style name="MyCustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#E3F2FD</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#E3F2FD</item>
    </style>

Comment: added this code and fix it. tnx your help my dear friend. code is : <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>