# Toolbar ActionMode background pre Lollipop does not work

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar

Toolbar ActionMode seems to ignore my style on devices pre Lollipop.

Here is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#DD000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#8A000000</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->

    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/secondary</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/toolbar_action_background</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_action_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

And my toolbar xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

I've checked these questions:
[How to specify dark action mode with my theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118160/how-to-specify-dark-action-mode-with-my-theme)
[Toolbar and Contextual ActionBar with AppCompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7/26450875)
[Unable to style action mode when using Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374774/unable-to-style-action-mode-when-using-toolbar)

Expected behaviour, works fine on lollipop:

[image]

How it looks on kitkat:

[image]

Comment: Here is similar question, see my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121515/how-to-fix-copy-paste-layout-bug-in-edittext/29123467#29123467), vote up if it helps.

Comment: @Harry as you can see im already using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as a parent theme?

Comment: Post your main layout.

Comment: @Harry check http://pastebin.com/YVyAqNpp

Comment: Clear extra styles, just use  <item name="actionModeBackground">yourColor</item> and hope you have declared lollipop styles in values-21 folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved by specifying booth android namspace and without in my theme:

```
...
       <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
...

<style name="ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_action_background</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/toolbar_action_background</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `Toolbar`'s theme:

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

The first `style`, you didn't give a name. You missed some lines. Then, let's suppose the `style` which has no `name`, its `name` is `ToolbarStyle` which has a line of `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>` which does matter. Then at your `Toolbar` layout, replace your `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` by `app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"`. Then `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>` will color your `Toolbar`'s background. Are we clear now?

Comment: could you elaborate on that? What do you mean? :)

Comment: @Richard I have re-edit my answer, take a look again.

Comment: @SilenKnight that does not make sense, `app:theme` on the toolbar is for its child view only, for instance text inside the toolbar. Your answer does not affect toolbar ActionMode behavour